# Cannot add TXT records to firebase DNS domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a firebase domain which looks like : https://my-app-id.firebaseapp.com/

I'm trying to create a Dynamic Link with this domain, but it fails on the Verify step.

It says **"We couldn't verify your domain web.app. Check your settings and try again."**

I cannot find any settings where to add this TXT record into the Firebase integrated domain, all I can find is for a custom domain, but this is not custom, it is from firebase.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you're having trouble configuring Firebase products using the console, I suggest contacting Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

The TXT record is need if you have a custom domain.

If you don't have a custom domain you must use one provided by google, which is something like example.page.link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: I do use a firebase domain, I created it from firebase console on Hosting section.

Comment: @tibbus what Domain did you enter before getting to the step you show in the screenshot?

Comment: my-app-id.firebaseapp.com  . Where "my-app-id" is my firebase app id, I got the domain from Firebase Hosting.

Comment: Can you try using "my-app-id.page.link" or other ending in "page.link"? You can't use  exactly your hosting domain for dynamic link (see here why https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains?authuser=0#using_your_web_domain_for)